# Python, проблема BULK INSERT импорта CSV в MS SQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, pandas, csv

Генерирую CSV под Windows

```python
for chunk in pandas.read_sql(query, cnn, chunksize=chunksize):
    df_csv = chunk.to_csv(rf'C:\...\Python\CSV\output_{count}.csv',
                          sep=';',
                          na_rep='NULL',
                          line_terminator='\r\n',
                          mode='w',
                          index=False)
```

потом пытаюсь то что нагенерил залить в сиквел балком

```sql
BULK INSERT [TestBase].[dbo].[CSV]
FROM 'C:\...\Python\CSV\output_1.csv'
WITH
(
    DATAFILETYPE = N'CHAR', 
    --FIELDQUOTE = '"',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    --CODEPAGE = 'UTF-8',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',  
    ROWTERMINATOR = N'\r\n',  
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\...\Python\CSV\myErrorData.log',
    TABLOCK
)
```

Ни ошибок, ни результата.

До замены типа строчного разделителя с `\n` на `\r\n` были ошибки

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 9 (IsResolved).

и

> Row 2 File Offset 194 ErrorFile Offset 0 - HRESULT 0x80020005

Comment: Хммм, врядли вам помогут без доп. информации... В логах что-то есть? Пробовали залить маленький CSV файл?

Comment: @MaxU в этом файле 10 строк. В логах ничего подозрительного.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. При формировании CSV файла в пандас нужно NULL значения формировать как `''`, т.е. указать вместо `na_rep='NULL'` -> `na_rep=''`. Также меняем `line_terminator='\r\n'` на `line_terminator='\n'`.
2. Далее при массовой вставке данных указываем следующее:

```sql
BULK INSERT [TestBase].[dbo].[CSV]
FROM 'C:\...\Python\CSV\output_1.csv'
WITH
(
    DATAFILETYPE = 'CHAR', 
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    CODEPAGE = '65001',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A',
    KEEPNULLS,
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\...\Python\CSV\myErrorData.log',
    TABLOCK
)
```